# Add a check box in Menu Settings

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I'm looking for the appropriate hook to add a check box in Menu Settings, and if it exists, how to save the value as an option .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any action hooks available for adding custom checkboxes to the Menu Settings section (Github[`/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6f86cedb09f4ad42c5443cf5cc0c46b30bd41010/wp-admin/nav-menus.php#L954)). For registering menu locations, you should use [`register_nav_menus()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/).

Comment: actually i need to add a checkbox, in addition to the default ones

Comment: @YounesDro With "default ones" do you mean "Primary" and "Social menu" or something else? What should the checkbox do or control?

Comment: yes "Primary" and "Social menu". I want: when the user creates a new menu, propose a check box in the "Menu Settings" section, so that I can retrieve the menu in the Front end and add it to the site's footer.

Comment: @YounesDro To add new menu locations for your theme, use `register_nav_menus()` in your `functions.php`file. Refer to the documentation for further details.

Comment: I explain better: I want to offer a quick option (custom checkbox), this box, if the user checks it, I will display the menu in the footer. I don't want to create menus, no, I just want to recover the menu created by the user himself

Comment: @YounesDro Yes, that is exactly what `register_nav_menus()` is for. You use it to register a new menu location, e.g "Footer menu", which will appear as a checkbox under the previously registered ones, i.e. "Primary" and "Social Menu". After a user has created a menu and assigned it to the registered custom menu location (i.e. ticks the "Footer menu" checkbox), you can retrieve it in your footer template file for example with `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu-slug') );`

Comment: Menu documentation, https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: okay i will try that out and i'll see if it meets my needs.